# What are kernel blocks in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

In the article "How to set up Xcode to run OpenCL code, and how to verify the kernels before building" NeXTCoder referred to some code as the "Short Answer", i.e. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/XCodeHelloWorld/XCodeHelloWorld.html.

In that code the author says "Wrap your kernel code into a kernel block:" without explaining what is a "kernel block". (The OpenCL Programmer Guide for Mac OS X by Apple makes no mention of kernel block.)

The host program calls "square_kernel" but the sample kernel is called "square" and the sample kernel block is labelled "kernelName" (in italics).  Can you please tell me how to put the 3 pieces together:kernel, kernel block & host program to run in Xcode 5.1? I only have one kernel. Thanks.

Comment: When talking about the "article", you seem to refer to the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046035/how-to-set-up-xcode-to-run-opencl-code-and-how-to-verify-the-kernels-before-bui

Answer (score 1):

It's not really jargon. It's closure-like entity.

OpenCL C 2.0 adds support for the clang block syntax. You use the ^ operator to declare a Block variable and to indicate the beginning of a Block literal. The body of the Block itself is contained within {}, as shown in the example (as usual with C, ; indicates the end of the statement).The Block is able to make use of variables from the same scope in which it was defined.

Example:

```
int multiplier = 7;
int (^myBlock)(int) = ^(int num) {
    return num * multiplier;
};
printf(“%d\n”, myBlock(3));
// prints 21
```

Source:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.1/docs/man/xhtml/blocks.html

Answer (score -1):

The term "kernel block" only seems to be a jargon to refer to the "part of the code that is the kernel". Particularly, the kernel block in this case is simply the function that is declared to be a kernel, by adding `kernel` before its declaration. Or, even simpler, and from the way how the term is used on this website, I would say that "kernel block" is the same as "kernel".

The *`kernelName`* (in italics) is a placeholder. The code there shows the general pattern of how to define *any* kernel:

- It is prefixed with `kernel`
- It returns `void`
- It has a name ... the *`kernelName`*, which may for example be `square`
- It has several input- and output parameters

The reason why the kernel is called `square`, but invoked with `square_kernel` seems to be some magic that is done by XCode: It seems to read the `.cl` file, and creates a `.h` file that contains additional declarations that are derived from the `.cl` file (as can be seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234953/opencl-xcode-incorrect-kernel-header-being-generated-for-custom-data-type-ar), where a kernel called `rebound` is defined, and GCL generated a `rebound_kernel` declaration).

Comment: Marco 13's answer to racker's question was very helpful. Can someone recommend a good source for learning how to put an OpenCL program together on Xcode 5.1 using C++11 that contains more "how to" and less "you can".